# How to fix cursor issue from content editable

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

The final update of the post with last achievements of purpose. There is input field. Need to display block that contain `img` and none-displayable `span` with text. Snippet below did the task. But it has bug. And I can not change `contenteditable` because it belong external site and my code run in browser extension.

Run snippet. Click end of line, press left arrow button a few times. Your cursor moving through images to text. It's okay. Now press right arrow button and try to arrived end of line. When cursor get there first image, cursor's selection disappears. Another words, we can move cursor from right to left, but fail from left to right.

```css
.editor {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="editor" contenteditable="true">text <span contenteditable="false"><span class="hide"> DogePls </span><img alt="DogePls" src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/55c7eb723d8fd22f20ac9cc1/1x.webp"></span><span contenteditable="false"><span class="hide"> DogePls </span><img alt="DogePls" src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/55c7eb723d8fd22f20ac9cc1/1x.webp"></span><span contenteditable="false"><span class="hide"> DogePls </span><img alt="DogePls" src="https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/55c7eb723d8fd22f20ac9cc1/1x.webp"></span></div>
```

If between images will any symbols, bug fix. But I need not symbols there. Because input field is message sender for chat where user can typing in any place.

I tried add pseudo element, bug still reproduce.

```css
span[contenteditable=false]:after {
    content: "space";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "alive"

Comment: You could put a non breaking space immediately after but that still doesn’t make the content editable (ie deleteable). Could you describe exactly what the editing requirement is?

Comment: @ATP freely moving carriage and delete image

Comment: Just to understand your situation, why can't you use an `img` tag?

Comment: By “freely move carriage” do you mean place the cursor anywhere in the span and anywhere in the parent div and that the span should be editable e.g. the user could delete its replacement content (or part thereof e.g. if there are two urls in it you could delete just one)?

Comment: ‘ Objects inserted using the CSS content property are anonymous replaced elements. They are "anonymous" because they don't exist in the HTML markup.’ from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element so we are never going to make that replaced span editable. If you can’t use img, and as @MfyDev has asked, it would be useful to understand, is any other markup or CSS property banned?

Comment: @AHaworth banned only `img`, any other allow. Editable as entire block.

Comment: @AHaworth I also tried to find source code of `HTMLImageElement` in order to define custom-mirror of `img` to just change `img` name to `my-img`. But I dont sure that browser allow it and didn't find.

Comment: @MfyDev I describe situation in [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76842516/how-to-display-image-without-img-tag-and-save-carriage-moving)

Comment: i get it, some people aren't that fluent in english, but... uh... ... what.

Comment: Why don't you add non-breaking space character after each image dynamically so that the cursor can navigate smoothly through the content without disappearing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that content will work in this context because:

> ‘ Objects inserted using the CSS content property are anonymous replaced elements. They are "anonymous" because they don't exist in the HTML markup.’

(from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element)) so we are never going to make that replaced span deletable.

So here is a method using background image and setting the font-size to whatever size you want that emoji to be in relation to the surrounding text.

```html
<div contenteditable=true>
  3) span tag with background-image:
  <span contenteditable=false style="display: inline-block; font-size: 2em; background-image: url(https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/58d2e73058d8950a875ad027/1x); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center; text-align: right;">&emsp;</span>
</div>
```

UPDATE: there is a requirement to keep the text that is in the span element within the DOM, but not to make it visible (it is in that sense replaced by the image - but as above this won't let us do the right thing edit-wise).

I'm not sure I recommend the below snippet, it seems fussy and therefore could be liable to fragility, however in case it's useful in the particular context in which it's required I include it. Basically, it keeps the text in the span, but 'replaces' it by fixing the width and height of the span to whatever is required for the emoji, hides the overflow text and disguises the remaining text by putting a before pseudo element on top with the emoji image as background.

Note: it was not possible to make the text transparent (or the font-size 0) which had been my initial thought because the caret then disppeared.

```html
<style>
  div span {
    --size: 28px;
    /* set to whatever you want the size of the emoji to be */
  }
  
  div span::after {
    content: '';
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: var(--size);
    height: var(--size);
    background-image: url(https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/58d2e73058d8950a875ad027/1x);
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-color: white;
  }
</style>
<div contenteditable=true style="position: relative;">
  3) span tag with background-image:
  <span contenteditable=false style="width: var(--size); height: var(--size); display: inline-block; color: black; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-align: right; position: relative; margin-right: 1px;">Wowee</span>.
</div>
```

Comment: Can we do the same with invisible text in span? Like `<span contenteditable=false style="...">Wowee</span>`

Comment: Can you describe a bit more what you mean by 'invisible'? Is it to be 'invisible' (that is, not read out) to screen readers - i.e. is it to 'disappear' from the DOM, or is it to be just not seen and not take up any space on the screen?

Comment: Text is not take up any space on the screen (only image with own size) and the same time text exists in DOM.

Comment: Is there any text after the image usually or definitely none? (This makes a difference as to what solution, if any, there can be).

Comment: I have added a snippet which assumes there is some following text (just a full stop will do!)

Comment: Please, check update in post

Comment: I've looked at your update but am not sure why using pseudo element isn't OK. Can you tell me what the bug is in my (new) answer? Thanks.

Comment: Almost perfect solution, but cursor (carriage) don't display if we remove dot symbol.

Comment: No, and you are going to have to make sure your text does end with something other than one of those spans. As you already have JS this won't be difficult, and of course for a flowing text you are unlikely to have to do it at all as the chances of a one of those spans being the last thing in the whole text are probably not high (not that I know your full context!). Hopefully someone can come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

this may help:

```html
    <div contenteditable=true>
        span tag:
        <span style="content: url(https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/58d2e73058d8950a875ad027/1x)">Wowee</span>
        &nbsp;
    </div>
```

you just need some selectable area after you span to click on, which   adds it, or you may be able to do so using css (padding, .etc).

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why it works (Chrome), but here you go:

(btw, in Firefox all of your 3 examples work, you need to hit the backspace 3 times ,but they do)

```html
<div contenteditable>
  3) span tag with "#8203":
  <span style="content: url(https://cdn.betterttv.net/emote/58d2e73058d8950a875ad027/1x)"></span>
  &#8203;
</div>
```

(I don't suggest any usage of `contenteditable` as it full of bugs and unexpected behaviors, therefore I see no point in even trying to understand what's going on)

Comment: Unfortunately, `#8203;` interpret as symbol and carriage need to move twice. I can't change `contenteditable` because the case with external site out of my control.

Comment: @Viewed What do you mean by "carriage" ? do you mean the cursor? if so In my browser you don't need to delete/move twice.

Comment: Yes, cursor. Click end of line, press `right arrow`, then press `backspace` a few times.

Answer (score 0):

Add non-breaking space character after each image dynamically so that the cursor can navigate smoothly through the content without disappearing.

```
<script>
    const editor = document.getElementById("editor");

    function addNonBreakingSpaceAfterImages() {

        const images = editor.querySelectorAll("img");

        images.forEach((image) => {

            const nbsp = document.createTextNode("\u00A0");

            // Insert the non-breaking space after image
            image.parentNode.insertBefore(nbsp, image.nextSibling);

        });
    }

    addNonBreakingSpaceAfterImages();
    editor.addEventListener("input", addNonBreakingSpaceAfterImages);
</script>
```